# How do I run Drupal SimpleTest example from Examples for Developers from the CLI?

Tags: testing

I've been running tests from a helper_module_preprocess_html function that I trigger on reload. I think I need to level up with testing. I have a vanilla installation of Drupal, downloaded and enabled Examples and SimpleTest modules, and for the life of me I can't figure out how to get the simple test example tests to run from the command line on Ubuntu 14.14. How do I use Drupal's testing system? I'm lost and the documentation on the internet isn't helping.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that SimpleTest requires a version number in the .info file. I added testing_api = 2.x in the .info file and now it works.